# Firefox 88: No window redrawing after upgrade

Tags: firefox

On XUbuntu 20.10: I upgraded Firefox from version 87 to 88 today. Now, its window doesn't redraw/rerender its content. The windows redraw/rerender once only when I resize them.

*What I tried*

- Safemode solves the problem
- Disabling all addons does not help

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: No problem with FF 88 on ubuntu 20.04.2 here. is it worth checking with bugzilla.mozilla.org as a bug report?

Comment: There are nowadays graphical issues with the current 5.8.0-50 kernel. Perhaps try booting to 5.8.0-48 to see whether the problem then also occurs. Otherwise, probably disabling hardware acceleration may stop the problem (at the expense of graphical performance).

Comment: No bug report found; kernel 5.8.0-49 (before the latest sys update) has same problem. turning off HW accel did the trick

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround: `disabling hardware acceleration` worked:

- open browser in safe mode (firefox --safe-mode)
- type `about:preferences` in address bar
- search for `hardware`
- uncheck `use recommended performance settings`
- uncheck `use hardware acceleration`